# How to capture NSData with SHA1 hash in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, sha1, cryptography

I'm having trouble computing a SHA1 hash from a string and then putting it back in another string. Here's what I do:

```
unsigned char hashedChars[20];
CC_SHA1([hashElements UTF8String], [hashElements lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], hashedChars);
NSData *hashedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashedChars length:20];
NSString *hash = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:hashedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%s", hash);
```

The result of the log is (null). I basically make a string by combining a few strings, then try to calculate the hash, which is stored in an NSData object and then retrieved and put back in the hash string. When I log hashedData, I can clearly see a result coming up - which appears to be correct. That should indicate that something goes wrong on the fourth line. But what? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA-1 is a 20-bytes binary chunk, not a valid UTF-8 string. This is why NSString's `initWithData:encoding:` fails. What is commonly used for a representation of hash sums is a HEX string. Basically, what you need is `[hashedData description]`.